# Ошибка при вызове деструктора: program.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова

Tags: c++

```
class accountBase {
protected:  
    struct account;
    account * pacc;   //начало массивa аккаунтов
    int  accN;        //кол-во аккаунтов
public:
    accountBase(){
        accN=0;
        pacc=0;
    };
    ~accountBase(){
        delete[] pacc;
    };
    struct account {
        char* name;
        char* login;
        char* password;
        char* category; 
    };
    int getAccN() {
        return accN;
    };

    void addacc(account*acc){   
        account*paccBuf=new account[accN+1];
        memcpy(paccBuf, pacc, sizeof(account)*accN);
        accN++;
        paccBuf[accN]=*acc;
        delete pacc;        
        pacc=&(paccBuf[0]); 
    };  
};
```

Что не так?

Comment: @ололо, Вы бы хоть какой компилятор используете написали.

Может быть проблема в том, что в `addacc()` Вы пишите `delete pacc`, а в деструкторе `delete [] pacc`.

В Вашем случае правильно везде `delete []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не класс, а кусок мусора.

1. Зачем Вам struct с указателями на char*? Сделайте вложенный класс с std::string и конструктором, который будет заполнять все члены.
2. Избавьтесь от работы с указателями на массив аккаунтов. Лучше уж задействовать стандартные контейнеры std::vector или std::list - сразу уйдут проблемы с работой с памятью.

Comment: @gecube, тогда от класса ничего не останется. Видимо тренируется человек на умозрительной задачке.

Comment: лучше сделать свой велосипед "vector или list" это лучшая тренировка! а уже в accountBase использовать std